# Runtime Error: Cannot set database in spark! [DBT + Spark + Thrift]

Tags: apache-spark, dbt, spark-thriftserver

Can anyone help me on this?
I'm getting error,`***Runtime Error: Cannot set database in spark!***` while running dbt model via Spark thrift mode with remote Hive metastore.

I need to transform some models in DBT using Apache Spark as the adapter. Now, I'm running spark locally on my local machine.
I started the thrift server as below with remote hive metastore URI.

1. Started master

> ./sbin/start-master.sh

2. Started worker

> ./sbin/start-worker.sh spark://master_url:7077

3. Started Thrift Server

> ./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --master spark://master_url:7077
> --packages org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark3-runtime:0.13.1 --hiveconf hive.metastore.uris=thrift://ip:9083

In my DBT project,

> ```
> project_name:
>   outputs:
>     dev:
>       host: localhost
>       method: thrift
>       port: 10000
>       schema: test_dbt
>       threads: 4
>       type: spark
>       user: admin
>   target: dev
> ```

While executing dbt run,
getting the following error.

```
dbt run --select test -t dev
Running with dbt=1.1.0
Partial parse save file not found. Starting full parse.
Encountered an error:
Runtime Error 
Cannot set database in spark!
```

Please note that there is not much info in dbt.log

---

***SOLUTION***

***This error was getting because of the " database" filed in the source yml file.***

Always schema, never database
Apache Spark uses the terms "schema" and "database" interchangeably. dbt understands database to exist at a higher level than schema. As such, you should never use or set database as a node config or in the target profile when running dbt-spark.
https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/spark-configs#always-schema-never-database

Comment: What do you see when you run `dbt debug`?

Your profile has the placeholder name, `project_name` still in it -- that needs to match the name you gave your project in `dbt_project.yml`. When you do `run` you might be grabbing the config from the wrong profile. Additionally, you're specifying a `target` with the `-t` option named `spark`, but the only target you have defined in your profile is named `dev`

Comment: @tconbeer
 , sorry for that, I forgot to update "dev" in the question.
in dbt debug,
Connection:
  host: localhost
  port: 10000
  cluster: None
  endpoint: None
  schema: test
  organization: 0
  Connection test: [OK connection ok]

All checks passed!

Comment: This error was getting because of the " database"  filed in the source yml file.

Comment: Yes, I had to remove the "database" setting in source.yml but I kept the "schema", with the database name:
`sources:
  - name: XYZ
    schema: "{{ var('database') }}"`

Answer (score 0):

schema **test_dbt** not exist in the hive
I think you need to create **test_dbt** database in Hive

**step1**. log in to spark cluster and stop thrift server and run spark-sql

**step2**. create database test_dbt

**step3**. restart thrift server

OR

you can use default schema like below

```yaml
dbt_spark_project:
  outputs:
    dev:
      host: spark-cluster
      method: thrift
      port: 10000
      schema: default
      threads: 4
      type: spark
  target: dev
```